# Alternative Copula Tails Meaning

Tags: copula, fat-tails

For a bivariate copula $C(u_1,u_2)$, tails are defined as the values $(u,u) \downarrow 0$ and $\uparrow 1$, i.e. the lower left and upper right corners. I would like to know what happens if we go into the other two corners, i.e. $(u_1, u_2) \rightarrow (0,1)$ and $(u_1, u_2)\rightarrow(1,0)$? Is there any meaning behind it?

Comment: A relationship in the copula space for (0,0) to (1,1) is a co-monotonic relationship (positive association), this can be captured by the Gaussian and Archimedean copula families.  A relationship in the copula space from (0,1) to (1,0) is a counter-monotonic relationship (negative association).  Of the popular copula families, only the Gaussian copula can capture this (although there are some papers out there for rotated Archimedean copulas).  I'm not sure if that helps with understanding how it might relate to tail dependence.

Comment: Note that for example also Student t, Frank and Clayton copulas are able to capture negative dependence within their standard parameter space. A systematic implementation of rotated copulas can e.g. be found in the R package VineCopula that is also part of the interactive [copulatheque.org](http://copulatheque.org).

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen any explicit definition, but you can always look at a "flipped" pair of the random variables re-scaled to uniform on [0,1] distributed ones, i.e. if your pair $(U,V) \tilde{} [0,1]^2$ has a negative association (e.g. Kendall's tau < 0), then $(U, 1-V)$ will be positive correlated. This allows you to use the same original tools to study/model tail dependence.